# Insertion & Merge sort algorithms - Anomalous timing results

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort, insertion-sort

I am trying to get runtimes for two sort algorithms in Java, insertion and merge sort.
The program runs both sorts on an unsorted ArrayList of 433 words multiple times and stores the elapsed times taken for 100, 200, 300, 400 and 
433 words (the whole array) to be sorted, then prints out the average time taken for each of these.

My code, I believe, is ok. However, I'm coming across a strange anomaly which I was wondering if anybody could help me understand.

Here are the results when both of the sorts are executed **once**: [image: 1]

Here are the results when both of the sorts are executed **10,000 times**: [image: 2]

When run once the results are I believe as expected, that is the insertion sort is faster for the lower amounts of elements sorted but the merge sort is faster for the higher amounts and the whole array.

However, when run 10,000 times, the average timings are way off, the insertion sort is massively faster for all amounts of elements sorted.

It's as if the insertion sort speeds up with each iteration, how can this be possible?

Code for both sort algorithms and method used for running multiple iterations of said sort algorithms - in comment below

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Isn't it because of [speculative execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution)?

Comment: You should include the important bits of the code: the sorting methods, and how you reset or initialize the array after each sort. Note that, when the array is already sorted, insertion sort may have a very easy time.

Comment: @tucuxi Here is a pastebin of the two algorithms and the method used to run multiple iterations of the algorithms https://pastebin.com/6bdHBTAk

The array used in each iteration is the same **unsorted** array. As you can see the sorting methods return a new sorted array rather than sort an already existing array.

Comment: Insertion sort is O(n^2) while merge sort is O(nlog(n)). Merge sort uses n additional memory, Insertion sort needs only 1 extra variable. Merge sort is usually recursive. Cache size and speed play a major role too, as does memory speed. Clock resolution is 1 microsecond at best with 10 microseconds typical for laptops. Java’s methods to do timing in nanoseconds can’t do better than the clock speed. Your arrays are pretty small which would favor insertion sort. You really need to be sure the data is truly random.

Comment: @Marichyasana Would this explain why the results for one execution of both sorting algorithms are as expected but not for many though? The unsorted array is identical for every iteration in both sorts, surely if the results are as expected for 1 iteration of both sorts, the results would be as expected for 10,000 iterations where the timings are simple totalled and divided by 10,000 to find the average? Or do you believe I will get more accurate results with a larger array?

Comment: The JIT compiler compiles parts of java source as it is encountered. You can learn about these things in a good book on algorithms such as "Algorithms 4th Edition", by Robert Sedgwick at Princeton. A copy is available on their web site.

Comment: Where is the code that generates or reads in the arraylist strings? Link to a [better example of top down merge sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665863/mergesort-implementation-is-slow/41668335#41668335). You would need to convert this to java and strings (change the compares to use compareto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity of these algorithms is well known: **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** for insertion sort and **O(N.log(N))** for merge sort.

Here are possible reasons for your unexpected observation:

- A dataset of 400 strings is not very large, the quality of implementation may be more important than the sheer complexity of the algorithms.
- your implementation of insertion sort is not very efficient but at least it operates in place, hence with an effective time complexity of **O(N<sup>2</sup>)**. Yet you should remove the measuring code that executes every 100 elements with a non trivial complexity.
- your implementation of merge sort is quite inefficient: you allocate multiple dynamic arrays one element at a time for each split and merge phase. This is very time consuming, and causes a lot of objects to be allocated and left dangling almost immediately for the garbage collector to reclaim at great expense.
- A single call to merge sort might perform better than insertion sort, if the timing is meaningful at all, but many calls might trigger the garbage collector, with a substantial overhead, although your timings do not show evidence of this, potentially because 10000 iterations is not enough.
- The real explanation is actually simple: since your insertion sort implementation sorts the dataset in place, it is already sorted for each subsequent call, which is the optimal case for insertion sort with linear complexity.

You should sort copies of the initial dataset for a more meaningful benchmark. And also look for a better merge sort implementation that uses a single temporary array and sorts the elements in place and avoid dynamic Arrays when the size is known in advance.